# How to strip obfuscated email headers

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regex spam filter that will block subjects like these:

```
Subject:
..B..R..E_G-U E_T..___W..A..T..C..H-E S -_A T-___C H_E-A..P___P R-I_C E! .
-G_U..C..C_I..-..W_A_T C-H E_S---..A..T __C-H..E A P_--..P_R..I C..E
..C_H..O_P..A_R D---W-A T-C_H E S -- A_T.._-C..H-E A P_--P..R..I C_E!
```

I was able to come up with:

```
w([^a-zA-Z0-9]){1,3}a([^a-zA-Z0-9]){1,3}t([^a-zA-Z0-9]){1,3}c([^a-zA-Z0-9]){1,3}h([^a-zA-Z0-9]){1,3}e([^a-zA-Z0-9]){1,3}s([^a-zA-Z0-9]){1,6}
```

to trap the standard variations on "watches", though I doubt that it will catch them if they start spelling with Unicode.  Not to mention that it is not only non-elegant, it's so ugly my cat tried to bury it!

What is a better way?

It looks like Mozilla is using Javascript formatted regex -- http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: I think regular expressions aren't the answer to everything, though, of course, sometimes it's the only tool you have.

Comment: How about marking it as spam when there are excess number of non-alphanumeric characters in the title?

Comment: Sorry, I think it's javascript regex

Comment: Are you trying to filter messages in your client (Thunderbird perhaps?) or do you have your own mail server for which you are trying to implement these rules (like PostFix using Sieve)?

Comment: This is in Thunderbird, with filtaQuilla add-on

Comment: isSpam(subject.replace(/[^\w\s]+/g,"")) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your regex will work, but if you just want to clean it up some, try this:

`w[\W_]+a[\W_]+t[\W_]+c[\W_]+h[\W_]+e[\W_]+s`

I wouldn't consider any more elegant, but it's cleaner.

Use `\W` for "non-word characters" (it's shorthand for `[^A-Za-z0-9_]`), combined with `_` to end up with the same meaning you had: `[^A-Za-z0-9]`.

Use `+` rather than a quantifier with a specific amount, since it will probably vary and really at least one in each spot would indicate spam.

If you want to try something more elegant to try catching other subjects in the same pattern (which is what regex is good for), use this:

`(\w[\W_]+){4,}`

Comment: Unfortunately \W won't get the underscores (_) :(

Comment: I loaded a hundred or so email heading into a file to test. With `(\w[\W_]+){4,}` it matched the subs I wanted, but it also matched a few that I don't understand: `Where do we send this?`, `Your Amazon.com order has shipped (#999-1234567-8901234)` and `Congress is Attacking D.C.'s...`. Actually, I do understand the last one, with "D.C.", but it matched only the final two char of the "where do we send this", the "s?", and when I copied that same line elsewhere in the file, it didn't match, only the one instance.

Comment: The 'Amazon' heading truncated everything after "has'. `w[\W_]+a[\W_]+t[\W_]+c[\W_]+h[\W_]+e[\W_]+s` works fine *unless* two of the char on the 'watches' word are together, with nothing between, in which case it fails. I changed it to `w[\W_]*a[\W_]*t[\W_]*c[\W_]*h[\W_]*e[\W_]*s` and, while still verbose, it works finest kind, and far more elegant than what I had.  Thank you!